# How do I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows XP?

Tags: dual-boot

I have recently become a fan on Ubuntu and I wanted to get it on my old computer. I downloaded the 32 bit software and I have burned it to a usb stick in fat32. While on the installation bit of Ubuntu when I boot it up, press F2, change the priority of booting up the computer, all that, it doesn't give me an option of running Ubuntu along side of Windows. It just says, "Delete the whole disk" and also "Something other"
Could someone please help?
Thanks.